# Discord.py, Break оператор не выполняется

Tags: python-3.x, discord

Все как в заголовке, ошибок например: break outside - не пишет других ошибок также нет,

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')
wordfilter = [#Плохие слова]
vse = [#Все гифки] 

@client.event #Проверка бота на сервере
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected')

@client.event
async def on_message(message): #Фильтр чата
    for gifsrok in vse: #Удаление всех гифок через 40 секунд
        if gifsrok in message.content:
            await message.delete(delay=40.00)
        #Za Warudo! Команда которая запрещает писать гифки на время
        if message.content == 'Za Warudo!': pass
        elif gifsrok in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(':timer')
        if message.content == 'Then!':
            break
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Вот цикл 

    for i in wordfilter: #Удаление всех запрещенных гифок
        if i in message.content:
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send('Ban', delete_after=4.00)

client.run('ODAzMjEyMDYyNDczNzE1NzUy.YA6fhg.wZbKolXSraQ2gVPupu0W8HixaD8')
```

Comment: недавно попытался изменить с
`if message.content == 'Za Warudo!': pass
 
                    elif gifsrok in message.content:`
на `if message.content == 'Za Warudo!' and gifsrok in message.content` вообще перестал удалять гифки

Comment: Ну, так посмотрите, что находится в `message.content`. Очевидно, что там не `'Then!'`.